# Deploying multi module maven project with Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml, multi-module

I have a multi module Maven application. The project structure is like

```
parent
 |_ main
    |_ pom.xml   //<dependency> library_project, <packaging> jar
 |_ library
    |_ pom.xml
 |_ pom.xml    // with two <modules> and <packaging> pom
```

I have nexus repository and was trying to deploy it to AWS with Jenkins. But I am unable to change Jenkins settings since it's a provided service from another company. The Jenkins job success, but at the final step because it was uploading `parent.pom` in the `parent/target` folder instead of `main.jar` in the `parent/main/target` folder. In the end, the cloud service reported deployment error since it expect a .jar file but got a .pom file.

I am not very familiar with Jenkins, but I am guessing Jenkins find the parent pom and decide the final artifact should be `<parent_artifact_id>.pom`? I tried to change settings/plugins in POMs in order to let Jenkins upload the correct jar (i.e., `parent/target/main.jar`) but none of them works so fat. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: You want to let maven do the deploy (in a two step so you don't get a partial deploy if a module fails, so mvn clean verify; mvn deploy). You'd need to share your Jenkins config (pipeline or UI, maven step, n xus deploy plugin, etc.). For more, but it's all documented here, by aApache and Sonatype.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I agree with @lanW in the comments. It's highly related to the Jenkins settings. I will check with them about detail implementations. Thanks, i will close this.